# getting dynamically created check box value in php if checked or not checked by php and jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, pdo

I had

1 text field
3 check box
1 add more button
1 submit button

On click of add more button 1 text field and 3 check again added

I entered data in text field and checked some of check box

On submit the form ineed. Data of the text field with corresponding check box value by using jQuery and php

Comment: Be easier to show your code than trying to explain

Comment: On mobile i cannot submit the code

Comment: No laptop at home?

Comment: I will submit the code by tomorrow by reaching office in that time kindly give a response

Answer (score 0):

The problem with checkbox is that if it is not checked then it is not posted with the form. If you check a checkbox and post a form you will get the value of the checkbox in the $_POST variable , if it's unchecked no value will be assigned to the $_POST variable.
So as to know which checkbox is checked assign a distinct value to it.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
echo 'Checkbox: ';
print_r($_POST['checkbox']);
}



if(isset($_POST['text'])){
$text=$_POST['text'];
echo 'Textbox: ';
print_r($text);

}
}
  ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="tests.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="check"  value="1">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="check"  value="2">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="check"  value="3">
<br>
<input type="text" name="text[]" class="text">
<br>

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#add').on('click',function()
{
var breaks="<br>"
var checkbox="<br>";
var textbox="<br><input type='text' name='text[]' class='text'>";
var check_length=$('.check').length;

console.log(check_length);
for(var i=check_length+1;i<check_length+4;i++)
{   
    checkbox=checkbox+"<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' class='check' value='" + i + "'><br>";
    

}
$('input[type="text"]').last().after(checkbox,textbox);
});
    });
</script>

</html>
```